# Implementing HttpComponent's HttpAsyncClient with Multipart Entity

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I would like some help, clarification on using HttpAsyncClient with multipart entity. Basically I am trying to upload content of a file (byte[]) as a MultiPart Body using HttpAsyncClient. 
Sample of how I am using it:

```
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    httpAsyncClient.start();

    MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    reqEntity.addPart("file",new ByteArrayBody(Base64.decodeBase64(fileContent),"");
    reqEntity.addPart("fileSize",new StringBody("1234"));
    reqEntity.addPart("fileName",new StringBody("xyz.txt"));
    reqEntity.addPart("fileType",new StringBody("text/plain"));
    reqEntity.addPart("SEQ_NUM",new StringBody("23432"));

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(endpointUrl);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity.build());

    Future<HttpResponse> future = httpAsyncClient.execute(httppost, null);
    httpAsyncClient.close();
```

Below are the Pom Dependences added to the project for this implementation:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, I am blocked at a place where the following exception is thrown:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multipart form entity does not implement #getContent()

I have did lot of search over the internet and could find very little details about the new HttpAsyncClient implementation. I found some users been asked similar questions but none of the solution worked for me.

[HttpAsyncClient Multipart Entity not working?]
In the below link a user suggested to wrap the MultipartEntity instance with BufferedHttpEntity. So, I updated the code as below(not sure its correct) but still the same exception.

```
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    httpAsyncClient.start();

    MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    reqEntity.addPart("file",new ByteArrayBody(Base64.decodeBase64(fileContent),"");
    reqEntity.addPart("fileSize",new StringBody("1234"));
    reqEntity.addPart("fileName",new StringBody("xyz.txt"));
    reqEntity.addPart("fileType",new StringBody("text/plain"));
    reqEntity.addPart("SEQ_NUM",new StringBody("23432"));

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(endpointUrl);
    httppost.setEntity(new BufferedHttpEntity(reqEntity.build()));


    Future<HttpResponse> future = httpAsyncClient.execute(httppost, null);
    httpAsyncClient.close();
```

I would appreciate your help in identifying the cause.

References:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/201311.mbox/%3c13034392.132.1384195516775.JavaMail.Hal@Harold-Rosenbergs-MacBook-Pro.local%3e

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/201206.mbox/%3C1339240012.2405.12.camel@ubuntu%3E

Answer (score 0):

MultipartFormEntity can not be used asynchronously. One of the options is to write the entity out to ByteArrayOutputStream and create a NByteArrayEntity out of it.

```
    File file = new File(filePath);
    ByteArrayBody body;
    body = new ByteArrayBody(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), file.getName());

    HttpEntity mEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .setBoundary("-------------" + boundary)
            .addPart("file", body)
            .build();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();      
    mEntity.writeTo(baoStream);

    HttpEntity nByteEntity = new NByteArrayEntity(baoStream.toByteArray(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    httppost.setEntity(nByteEntity );
```

Comment: I tried that but still no luck. Well with all my efforts I tried to find the solution i got nothing. So, now I changed my code to use Normal HttpClient reference.